# PDF being squeezed and losing aspect ratio in IOS 8 on Iphone

Tags: ios, iphone, pdf, aspect-ratio, ios8.1

I have a website that allows users to view PDF documents. In mobile safari in iOS 8 I am having issues with landscape oriented PDF's being squeezed to fit the window. This pdf should have a landscape orientation (it looks like the browser is forcing it into portrait). The user is being directly linked to the pdf file they wish to view aka: http://whatever.com/anygivenpdf.pdf

Here is a screenshot of the issue in the IOS simulator (Iphone 5, IOS 8.1). I do not have this issue in IOS 7. Any thoughts on a fix or where the issue is originating from? I'm thinking it's either way the PDF's are saved or something must be fixed for the browser itself.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I regard this primarily as a Safari bug in iOS 8.

However, I have found a way to modify a PDF document to avoid this problem. My method works only on a Mac:

- Open the existing PDF doc by the Preview app.
- Select "Export as PDF..." from the File menu.
- In the pop-up box where you select the new file name, click first on the button "Show details" in the lower left corner.
- Select the icon for landscape orientation!
- Give the document a new filename.
- Click Save.

(I run a Swedish version of Mac OS X, so I am not 100% sure that I have used exactly the correct terms used in the menus of the English version, but I think you will find your way based on my description.)

Credits to these posts, putting me on the right track:
https://discussions.apple.com/thread/6540211
and
http://www.appligent.com/my-pdf-document-is-rotated-how-do-i-fix-that/

In the second one, you will find a specific description on how to fix the problem using Acrobat Distiller, if you happens to have that application installed. That should be a way forward if you run Windows, I believe.